# Hyperbolic geometry

Tags: geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

Post Number: 45
Posted on Friday, 22 March, 2013 - 04:48 pm:
I was asked the following question and i do not have any clue on these. Could anyone help me in the beginning of this?

1. Show that there exists a tangent hyperbolic straight line at every point on a hyperbolic circle, horocycle, or hypercycle. Show that this tangent is perpendicular to the diameter at the point.
2. Prove that a hyperbolic circle is the locus of points that are a fixed distance from its center.
3. Let C be a hypercycle, and let L be the hyperbolic straight line that shares the same ideal points as C. Prove that the perpendicular distance from C to L is the same at every point of C.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's that with the first line?

Comment: These are all true. Some are easier in the Poincare disc model, some in the upper half plane. All done in existing books.

Comment: What is your definition of a hyperbolic circle, if it is not 2.? If you define it algebraically, what model do you use?

Comment: For the first question, i think that i choose a point on the hyperbolic circle and map it into 0 so that the whole hyperbolic circle is map to the x-axis accordingly so that i prove there is tangent at every point of hyperbolic circle?? Am i right ?

Comment: is there any book suggest any clue for that??

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are searching for $\tau$ and $\sigma$ iso-surfaces:

They are circles through two foci in the plane and their orthogonal trajectories are Apollonius circles.

[Hyperbolic Circles in Bipolar Coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipolar_coordinates)

Text Book reference (Differential Geometry by H.W. Guggenheimer, Dover, 1977 )  for classic hyperbolic circles:

Chapter on ***Inner Geometry of Surfaces***

Theorem 11-15 *Plane hyperbolic geometry is the geometry of the group $SL_2$ of projectivities of $ P^1$ acting as a group of motions in a plane.*