# Distance formula for points in the Poincare half plane model on a "vertical geodesic".

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

In  comment at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1381829/88985 at

[Distance of two hyperbolic lines](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1381727/distance-of-two-hyperbolic-lines)
is says (as i interpreted it) that the distance between two points $(a,r)$ and $(a, R)$ in the Poincaré half-plane model ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_half-plane_model ) is $ \ln(R) - \ln(r) $.

I tried to deduct this formula from the formulas:

$$ \operatorname{dist} (\langle a, r \rangle, \langle a, R \rangle) = \operatorname{arcosh} \left( 1 + \frac{  {(R - r)}^2 }{ 2 r R } \right) $$

and 
$$\operatorname{arcosh} {x} =\ln \left(x + \sqrt{x^2 - 1} \right) $$

but failed miserably, (especially the bit under the square root didn't want to simpify)

can somebody show me the deduction?

ADDED LATER:

following https://math.stackexchange.com/users/208255/user24142

's suggestion (below) and other comments I come to

$$ \operatorname{dist} (\langle a, 1 \rangle, \langle a, R \rangle) = \operatorname{arcosh} \left(\frac{1}{2} \left( R + \frac{1}{R} \right) \right)$$

$$ = \ln \left(\frac{1}{2} \left( R + \frac{1}{R} \right) +\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}\left( R + \frac{1}{R} \right)^2 - 1 } \right) = $$

$$ = \ln \left(\frac{1}{2} \left( R + \frac{1}{R} \right) +\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{ R^2  - 2 +\frac{1}{R^2} \ } \right) = $$

$$ = \ln \left(\frac{1}{2} \left( R + \frac{1}{R} \right) +\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{ (R  - \frac{1}{R} )^2 } \right) = $$

$$ = \ln \left(\frac{1}{2} \left( R + \frac{1}{R} \right) +\frac{1}{2} \left( R  - \frac{1}{R} \right) \right) = \ln (R)$$

THANKS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$ {\cosh ^{-1}} \frac{(R+ 1/R)}{2} $$

$$= {\cosh ^{-1}} \frac{ e^ {\log (R)}+ e^{-\log(R)}}{2} $$

$$  = {\cosh ^{-1}} [ \cosh (\log R)] = \log R .  $$

EDIT1:

BTW, why do we assume unit (abs value) Gauss curvature? Should it not appear symbolically at least *in a formula* ?

$$ \operatorname{dist} (\langle a, r \rangle, \langle a, R \rangle) = \operatorname{ a \cdot \,arcosh} \left( 1 + \frac{  {(R - r)}^2 }{ 2 r R } \right) $$

Comment: The Poincaré half-plane model is only a model of an hyperbolic plane (for something that aproaches the real thing use a Pseudosphere https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudosphere ) I presume that in this model the  Gauss curvature is fixed at -1 i think you cannot even make an  Poincaré half-plane model  with a curvature of for example -2. There have been some questions about this, but never with a decent answer (so you could start a new one i guess :))

Comment: I am afraid your presumption could stand to scrutiny. If the maximum radius of cuspidal pseudosphere is $r_c=a$, then its Gauss curvature $K=−1/a^2$. If $r_c=a/√2$ then its K is doubled as also mentioned in the wiki.

Comment: maybe i misundersood, different  tracioids  can have different gaussian curvatures , but the  curvature  for the poincare half plane is always -1, (as i understand it) the wikipedia article is not very good in this , it more or less implies there is just one tracioid with a curvature of -1

Comment: The clarification I seek is, the "a" on the left hand side cannot simply vanish in any mathematical formula , that too in a *model*. Does it express that the RHS distance is independent of all radii "a" of the geodesics !! ?

Comment: not sure what you mean  the $a$ in $ \operatorname{dist} (\langle a, r \rangle, \langle a, R \rangle) $ is just a location on the x axis, boundary line in the halfplane model , and yes it vanish. But I guess you refer to another formula (adopted from the wikipage) $ \operatorname{dist} ( \langle a, r \rangle, \langle a+  r\sin\phi , r\cos\phi  \rangle ) = \operatorname{arcosh} \left( \operatorname{sec} \phi \right) $ where $a$ and $r$ vanish. but better to ask a new question about this.

Answer (score 1):

Well, to being with, assume that $r= 1$ and $R>1$. Now,

$$\begin{align*} \operatorname{dist} (\langle a, 1 \rangle, \langle a, R \rangle) &= \operatorname{arcosh} \left( 1 + \frac{  {(R - 1)}^2 }{ 2R }
\right)\\
&= \operatorname{arcosh} \left(\frac{1}{2} \left( R + \frac{1}{R} \right) \right)\\
&= \ln(R) \end{align*}$$

where the last line is accomplished by observation and knowledge of the $\cosh$ function. I claim that the case $R<1$ yields $-\ln(R)$, and that together these give the general result.

Just to round this out, we know that the distance function is continuous, and that it must be invariant under $z\mapsto az$ and $z\mapsto z+b$. From this, its possible to derive that the distance function along any vertical must be the same as the distance function along any other vertical, and that it must be the logarithm wrt some base. Our choice of base here guarantees that we have a curvature of $-1$, which guarantees several other nice things, like perfect triangles having area $\pi$, but just the isometries give us most of the important geometric facts. The specific distance function is, to some extent, a distraction imo.

Comment: thanks, but i still don't understand the bit 
$ \operatorname{arcosh} \left(\frac{1}{2} \left( R - \frac{1}{R} \right) \right) = \ln(R) $ (also added bit more to the question)

Comment: obvious typo middle line

Comment: @Narasimham right you are.

Answer (score 1):

Compute first the inverse of

$$y=\operatorname {arcosh}(x)=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}2$$

for positive $x$'s.

Whit the substitution $u=e^x$ we have $2y=u+\frac1u$. Multiplying both sides by $u$ we get the following quadratic equation:

$$u^2-2yu+1=0,$$

the solutions of which are

$$u^+=y+\sqrt{y^2-1}\ \text{ and } \ u^-=y-\sqrt{y^2-1}.$$

We need only the positive part

$$e^x=y+\sqrt{y^2-1}$$

and if $y\ge 1$ then we'll have real results.

Taking the natural logarithm of both sides we get

$$x=\ln\left(y+\sqrt{y^2-1}\right), \ y\ge 1.$$

In our case $y= 1 + \frac{  {(R - 1)}^2 }{ 2R }
\ge 1$, so we may substitute it in $y+\sqrt{y^2-1}.$ The result will be $R$.

This is why we may say that for $R\ge0$

$$\operatorname{arcosh}\left(1 + \frac{  {(R - 1)}^2 }{ 2R }\right)=\ln(R).$$